# Why does the current not divert in the inverting summing amplifier circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, inverting-amplifier, summing

[image]

Why is the current drawn from different sources in this circuit not diverted to other resistors? Why does current only flow through the Rf resistor?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Current flows through all of the resistors, not just Rf. I'm also not sure what you mean by "distributed to other resistors." Can you explain what you mean by that? How does your expectation differ from what the diagram shows?

Comment: The key to understanding it lays in recognizing that the opamp's output will mysteriously do whatever is needed to ensure that the (-) input is held very close to ground -- **at all times**. So if you are able to hold onto that idea -- assume it is true for now -- then the (-) input is at 0 V. (Close.) Therefore, the voltages applied will either source some current into the node or else sink some current out of the node. But the sum total of those currents, whatever they are, must be removed by pulling the sum out (or sourcing it in) by the output itself so as to make the sum zero. It works.

Comment: I1 I2 I3 can be negative, presenting reverse current flow.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the op-amp output produces a voltage that keeps the inverting input at 0 volts. That is the main point of negative feedback in this type of amplifier.

<sub>The op-amp's role in this circuit is to maintain the inverting input at 0 volts. That's why it's called a virtual ground circuit. By hook or by crook, the op-amp output (via Rf) drags or pushes the inverting input voltage to be at 0 volts (equal to the non-inverting input). So, each input current equals the relevant input voltage divided by the relevant input resistor</sub>

Comment: Then wouldn't it be as if each resistor and resistor Rf were connected in series? Why isn't the current drawn from each source calculated this way:
I1=V1/R1+Rf+Rl
I2=V2/R2+Rf+Rl
I3=V3/R3+Rf+Rl

Comment: No, it would be as if all input resistors were connected individually to ground (a virtual ground as we call it) @DoğukanKarakaya also, I have no idea what that formula refers to on a schematic.

Comment: What I mean is this: Let each input source be connected to the same ground. Why is the current drawn from V1 source calculated as I1 = V1/R1? Isn't Rf connected in series with R1? So shouldn't the formula be I1=V1/R1+Rf? The same will be true for other sources.

Comment: The op-amp's role in this circuit is to maintain the inverting input at 0 volts. That's why it's called a virtual ground circuit. By hook or by crook, the op-amp output (via Rf) drags or pushes the inverting input voltage to be at 0 volts (equal to the non-inverting input). So, you can assume that I1 does actually equal V1/R1. Ditto the others inputs.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for your answers. Since I don't know about opamps, I want to ask one last question. If the only job of the opamp is to keep the input at 0 volts, why don't we use a very high resistor instead of an opamp?

Comment: @DoğukanKarakaya you may have to make a sketch of what you mean but, without something that amplifies you won't get signal gain.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the input currents in the OP's schematic of an op-amp inverting summer do not pass through the other input sources, but only through Rf. The reason is that all input sources are positive. There would be no problem with understanding if at least one of the sources was negative.

I will answer the OP's question in more detail by developing the circuit idea in five steps.

### Series voltage summer

The simplest voltage summer is just a loop in which the input voltage sources are connected in series. Its main disadvantage is that some of the sources or the load are "floating" (ungrounded). For example, in the schematic below, the input voltage sources V1 and V2 are floating.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyUhri.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Parallel current summer

The simplest current summer is just a node in which the input current sources are connected in parallel and the output is shorted by a low-resistance load (ammeter in the schematic below). Here all the sources and the load are grounded.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhrg0s.png)</sup>

As you can see, a part (1 mA) of the currents exiting the input current sources I1 and I3 enter the input current source I2; the rest (1 mA) flows through the short connection (ammeter).

### Resistor voltage summer

From Ohm's law, we know that a resistor with resistance R can convert the voltage V into a current I = V/R. Then let's connect a resistor to each input of the current summer and replace the load with a high resistance (e.g., an open circuit or a voltmeter as in the schematic below).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdLiIK.png)</sup>

As you can see, the currents exiting the input voltage sources V1 and V3 enter the input voltage source V2. The explanation is that because there is no load connected, currents flow between the input sources.

### Inverting voltage summer

The resistor circuit above is simple but imperfect because its inputs and the load (if one is connected) affect each other; it is possible to have currents entering positive input sources and exiting negative ones. All these problems would be solved if its output voltage was equal to zero. But we need this voltage. Then we can **destroy it by applying an opposite in sign and equal in value quantity to serve as a new output quantity**.

For this purpose, we add another (fourth) input to this 3-input voltage summer by connecting another resistor R4 and applying another "input" voltage V4; also, we connect a null indicator NI (sensitive voltmeter) between the node and ground. Then we begin changing V4 until the null indicator NI is zeroed and the "magic" *virtual ground* appears. Try it by opening V4 *parameters* and adjusting it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRq1Cb.png)</sup>

Now the currents can only exit positive input voltage sources and only enter the negative one.
If a low-resistance load is connected to V4, it will draw current from V4, not from the input voltage sources as in the resistor voltage summer above. What a great idea!

### Op-amp inverting summer

Now all that remains is to assign this routine to an op-amp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feLJUY.png)</sup>

### Why In = Vn/Rn

As you can seen, in this famous op-amp circuit, each of the input currents (e.g., I1) is determined only by its voltage V1 and its resistance R1 (not by R1 + R4). This phenomenon is usually explained by the too abstract and vague "virtual ground" phenomenon. Here I will explain it by the more intuitive "negative resistance" phenomenon.

The op-amp creates a "mirror copy" Vout = -VR4. In other words, it adds as much voltage as it is lost across R4. Thus the op-amp output acts as a "negative resistor" with resistance -R4 which destroys the "positive resistance" R4 and the result is R4 - R4 = 0. Figuratively speaking,  the combination of R4 and the op-amp acts as a "piece of wire" with zero resistance.

That is why I1 = V1/R1 but not I1 = V1/(R1 + R4).

Answer (score 2):

Your questions assumes (or asks about) the three input currents interacting **with each other** at the opamp inverting input node.  They do not, and that is the sole duty of the opamp.  If that node were physically wired to GND, you would not assume that the three input currents interact because they all go to GND.

Within the gain and output current limitations of the opamp, that is true for the summing node; it does not move.  And since the three input resistors are (virtually) grounded, the only thing that can change the three input currents are the three input voltages.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_ground

Answer (score 0):

The opamp maintains a virtual ground at its negative input due to negative feedback.  The quality of the virtual ground is constrained by the open loop gain and the phase margin, so at frequencies approaching the GBW of the opamp, there may be significant bleedover between the inputs.  The opamp here is labeled "741" which is synonymous with "real opamp with considerable limitations", so you might see some of that effect in simulation.